# Eregi_replace para preg_replace

Tags: url, preg-replace

Expressão regular não é meu forte em PHP e necessito da ajuda de vocês.
Preciso transformar uma string que vem de um post apta a fazer parte de uma url. Exemplo:

"Caio não pegou um balde d'água" para "caio-nao-pegou-um-balde-dagua" e então ficaria:  com.br/caio-nao-pegou-um-balde-dagua

Atualmente uso eregi_replace e com o PHP 7 não me serve mais, e então preciso de um novo jeito para executar a mesma função.

Código:

```
public static function Url($texto){
    $texto = html_entity_decode($texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[aÃƒÂ¡ÃƒÂ ÃƒÂ£ÃƒÂ¢ÃƒÂ¤]','a',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[eÃƒÂ©ÃƒÂ¨ÃƒÂªÃƒÂ«]','e',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[iÃƒÂ­ÃƒÂ¬ÃƒÂ®ÃƒÂ¯]','i',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[oÃƒÂ³ÃƒÂ²ÃƒÂµÃƒÂ´ÃƒÂ¶]','o',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[uÃƒÂºÃƒÂ¹ÃƒÂ»ÃƒÂ¼]','u',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[ÃƒÂ§]','c',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[ÃƒÂ±]','n',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('( )','-',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('[^a-z0-9\-]','',$texto);
    $texto = @eregi_replace('--','-',$texto);
    return strtolower($texto);
}
```

Comment: Gabriel recomento o vídeo no youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPiTB4ho5DA =D. Em seguida o que deseja http://thiagomorello.com/blog/2013/01/como-gerar-urls-amigaveis-perfeitamente-com-php/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
    $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}

echo toAscii("Caio não pegou um balde d'água para caio-nao-pegou-um-balde-dagua");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783802/converting-string-into-web-safe-uri